# How to handle users managements with node js and mysql

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, kotlin

Is working with node js and mysql is reasonable in android app development ?
because all the tutorials I found is with mongodb and I can't use it because apparently my country is restrict from access it

what I want in my app is  user management and upload images

am coming from php so the user management can easily done with session but how it done here

so will mysql do this for me our should I use something else !?

Comment: Which country restricts mongodb??

Comment: its the other way around  , mongodb don't allow access from my country which is sudan

Comment: ok interesting !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, MongoDB is a no SQL database you will have some flexibilities there but SQL is more structured and it can be used with nodejs.

The use case is something you should think about. To give you an example suppose the data you are storing is not same for every user then NoSQL(Mongo DB) is preferred but there are ways around to do such things in SQL(MySQL) by normalizing the data.

So, You can use MySQL... In my opinion.

Here is one example you can try...

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp